# Ternary operator on auto_ptr content not working

Tags: c++, stl, auto-ptr

I initialize an auto_ptr to NULL and later in the game I need to know if it has NULL or not to return it or a new copy.

I've tried this

```
auto_ptr<RequestContext> ret = (mReqContext.get() != 0) ? mReqContext : new RequestContext();
```

And several other similar stuff casting and so, but g++ tries to invoke auto_ptrs nonexistent operator? (the ternary operator) instead of using RequestContext* for the ternary comparison.

Even if I cast it it doesn't work.

Any hint?

Edited the equal for non-equal

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? Are you getting a compile error message, or is the run time behaviour wrong (what behaviour are you getting instead)?  Why do you return mReqContext only when it's NULL?

Comment: What do you mean, "g++ tries to invoke auto_ptrs nonexistent operator?" ?

Comment: Apparently an overload is assumed (but ?: isn't overloadable)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I suppose the situation is analogous to the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

int main()
{
    std::auto_ptr<int> a(new int(10));
    std::auto_ptr<int> b = a.get() ? a : new int(10);
}
```

And here's Comeau's very enlightening error message:

```
"ComeauTest.c", line 7: error: operand types are incompatible ("std::auto_ptr<int>"
          and "int *")
      std::auto_ptr<int> b = a.get() ? a : new int(10);
                                         ^
```

Ternary operator requires compatible types for both results, you can't have it return user-defined object in one case and a naked pointer in the other. NB! `std::auto_ptr` takes a pointer in an **explicit** constructor, which means the ternary operator cannot implicitly convert the second argument to `std::auto_ptr`

And possible solution:

```
std::auto_ptr<int> b = a.get() ? a : std::auto_ptr<int>(new int(10));
```

Comment: Isn't the issue about the explicit constructor of auto_ptr rather than about the ternary operator?

Answer (score 2):

`mReqContext` is of type `auto_ptr<RequestContext>`, right? Then the problem may be incompatible types on both sides of the `:` because `new RequestContext()` yields a `RequestContext *`, but both must have a common type for the ternary operator to be usable.

Possible solutions: Either use

```
auto_ptr<RequestContext>(new RequestContext)
```

at the right side of the `:` or use

```
mReqContext.get()
```

at the left side of the `:`.

In both cases: Beware of the pointer ownership issues with `auto_ptr`! The (raw) pointer in an `auto_ptr` can be only be owned by a single `auto_ptr` object, so both of my "simple" solutions may not be what you want (the first one clears out `mReqContext` when it is non-zero, the second one doesn't but may lead to duplicate deletion of `mReqContext`).

Answer (score 1):

try

```
auto_ptr<RequestContext> ret;
ret.reset(new stuff here);
```

Comment: It's the same, the right side of the assignation is the problem, not the left one.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try, breaking that up into two lines?

```
RequestContext *p = (mReqContext.get() == 0) ? mReqContext : new RequestContext();
auto_ptr<RequestContext> ret = p;
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting it all into braces?

```
auto_ptr<RequestContext> ret =
    (mReqContext.get() == 0) ? (mReqContext) : (new RequestContext());
```

Comment: The braces are not a problem, it's the different types on the sides of :

Comment: Yeah, since UncleBens' answer, I know that, too. I was just guessing like some others here...

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are not assigning pointer to the auto_ptr, this will not work.
However, all these fragments compiling just fine:

```
#include <memory>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char * argv[] )
{
    auto_ptr<int> pX;
    pX.reset(pX.get() ? new int(1) : new int(2));
    pX = auto_ptr<int>(pX.get() ? new int(1) : new int(2));
    pX = auto_ptr<int>((pX.get()==NULL) ? new int(1) : new int(2));

    return 0;
}
```